# function for Loading data from python to postgres

Tags: python, pandas, database, postgresql, load

I am trying to load data from a CSV file, transform it and load it to postgres on adminer. I have got some code which i dont really understand but works for when I insert more than 2 columns of data into a table, I have a table with just one column I want to insert but the code gives me 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' and its due to cols = ','.join(list(datafrm.columns)) in the error comment.

1. How can I account for this so I can load 1 or more columns without error?
2. How can I make this code more agnostic?
   Any support will be greatly appreciated

```html
    # Define function using psycopg2.extras.execute_values() to insert the dataframe.
    def execute_values(conn, datafrm, table):
        # Creating a list of tupples from the dataframe values
        tpls = [tuple(x) for x in datafrm.to_numpy()]
        # dataframe columns with Comma-separated
        cols = ','.join(list(datafrm.columns))
        # SQL query to execute
        sql = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES %%s" % (table, cols)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        try:
            extras.execute_values(cursor, sql, tpls)
            print("Data inserted using execute_values() successfully..")
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as err:
            # pass exception to function
            show_psycopg2_exception(err)
            cursor.close()
    
    # Connect to the database
    conn = connect(conn_params)
    conn.autocommit = True
    execute_values(conn, datafrm, 'table')
```

Comment: Why run this through a dataframe at all? Python has `csv` module and `psycopg2` has [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from). Just go directly from CSV to the Postgres table.

Comment: It goes from CSV to dataframe to transform the data before loading to Postgres table. I have a partially working solution to this but cant make it work for all scenarios :(

Comment: First you should be using the `psycopg` module [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html)  to build dynamic SQL.  The problem seems to be upstream from this code, in that whatever is doing the transform from CSV to Pandas is creating a `Series` for the one column case instead of a `Dataframe`. As the error states a `Series` does not have a `columns` property.  Add the code for the CSV transform to your question.